# how to create a basic polygon?

Tags: libgdx, collision-detection, overlap, polygons

I want to create a polygon that will collide with a rectangle using overlapse(). The only problem I have is that I don't know how to create a polygon, and I mean **only** a polygon. Every time I tried to find it on the internet I find the most complicated codes ever. So if can you just show me how to create a polygon and explain how to declare it's shape it will be greatly appreciated.

The polygon looks about like this:

[image]

note: it should be symmetrical but i am not sure if i drew it symmetrical...

Comment: What do you think "polygon" means?

Comment: any shape that is not round, and if you ask it like this i think i am about to discover i am totaly dumb?

Comment: well, you are not wrong. But in programming, we usually deal with triangles... I don't know what libgdx offers in terms of collision detection, but with the shape you provided you will require pretty complex math to detect collision.

Comment: actually i just can declare a polygon and a rectangle and do if(Rect.overlapse(Poly)){

Comment: Really? That's actually pretty neat, I might have to take a look at that library :P

Comment: so i only want to know how to declare a polygon's sahape

Comment: It seems you can create a new polygon with "new Polygon(new float[]{0,0,bounds.width,0,bounds.width,bounds.height,0,bounds.height});" taken from [this question page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14359852/libgdx-properly-using-polygon-class). The parameter you use in that constructor is an array of floats where every odd element is an x offset from it's origin and every even element is a y offset from it's origin. So in my example it would create a square with the offset at 0,0 (first two elements) then then next vertex at width,0 then one at width,height and finally one at 0,height

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/math/Polygon.html#constructor.summary) on the polygon class, you can simply use it's constructor to define a new polygon. Example:

```
//we want to create a simple square shaped polygon
//we create an array to hold every vertex we need, there are 4 vertices
//this constructor uses 1 float array as parameter, where every two element define the position of 1 vertex
polygon = new Polygon(new float[]{ //so we pass a new float array to the constructor
                      0,0, //this is the x,y of the first vertex
                      width,0, //the second vertex
                      width,height, //the third
                      0,height}); //and the last
```

This is a simple example, but you should be able to figure out how to expand the shape. I'll give one more example to add an extra vertex to create a "house shape":

```
polygon = new Polygon(new float[]{ //so we pass a new float array to the constructor
                      0,0, //this is the x,y of the first vertex
                      width,0, //the second vertex
                      width,height, //the third
                      (width*0.5),(height*1.5), //this one is now extra, it adds one vertex between the last and the one before it
                      0,height}); //and the last
```

Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: sorry for the late response, but thank you very much. i understood all but is there a way to test the polygon? to see if it's the shape i wanted it?

Comment: i mean, if you can visualize it temporarily